# Add tag(s) to job search filter/feed

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs

Currently if I search by a keyword/tag such as `php` in the `what`, I get back all results with `php` anywhere in the posting.

However, if I click on the `php` tag, I get all postings tagged as `php`, but no ability to filter further (that I can see).

Clicking the tag populates the `what` field, which, as mentioned before, returns all postings that have that keyword anywhere in the description or tags.

Don't get me wrong, it's really nice to be able to do a full posting search.  But in my above example, more than one posting is tagged with various MS technology tags, and PHP is mentioned once in the posting, to the effect of "Oh, and it wouldn't hurt if you are familiar with PHP, too."

So it would be really great if I could apply tag filters to a search so that I could have a feed of postings where the company has that technology specifically in mind rather than as an afterthought.  I'll still do full-text searches to catch the others, but it's a lot more exciting to see a new post with my skill-set singled out.